# Rolling motion on a frictionless surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I had the following question:

> You are on a frictionless surface. How can you move horizontally if no horizontal force is exerted by pushing against the surface?
> $a.$ By rolling your body on the surface
> $b.$ By running on the surface
> $c.$ By spitting or sneezing
> $d.$ By jumping straight up

The answer given is option $c$, which I understand, by *conservation of momentum*. By why can't option $a$ be correct? If I understand correctly, for a rolling body the friction at the bottom most point would be zero, hence wouldn't it be possible for a body to roll on a frictionless surface?

Comment: You can roll, but since there is no friction, your center of mass will not move. You will simply roll on the spot.

Comment: @VincentThacker Technically, then it doesn't qualify as rolling but only as spinning.

Comment: @ACB Thanks, understood.

Comment: @VincentThacker If I understand correctly, even rolling requires static friction, so if there is not friction at all, would rolling on the spot even be possible?

Comment: @Metaxylene Yes, it would still be possible, because there is nothing stopping you from using the normal force to exert torque.

Comment: @VincentThacker But the normal force passes through the center of rotation, so that would not work I think.

Comment: @Metaxylene Not necessarily; it is still possible to exert normal forces off-center (and have non-zero torque).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **kinetic friction** at the contact point of a rolling body is zero. But not necessarily the **static friction**. Starting from rest, a wheel will "push itself off" from the contact point due to static friction acting the opposite way. Without any types of friction - not static, nor kinetic - you can never start moving your centre-of-mass.

The only method left is thus to throw something backwards. The combined centre-of-mass between you and the thrown mass (it could be an object, or your spit, or your sneezing exhaust gas and paricles etc.) is still stationary, but *you* will move, and so will the thrown mass.